# I'm assuming I have to do something manual with Res1 (a PowerShell hashtable in form of a string)

Tags: c#, powershell

I'd like to get the entire payload that comes back from PowerShell into a single class. I'm assuming Res1 and the others have to be dealt with as a custom string in order to get that into c# properties. It's still a work in progress...

It would be nice to have the info in class like the following:

```
MyClass{
  public string ComputerName { get; set; }
  public string CUsedSpace { get; set; }
  public string CFreeSpace { get; set; }
  public string DUsedSpace { get; set; }
  public string DFreeSpace { get; set; }
  public List<string>  FolderGroup1Names { get; set; }
  public List<string>  FolderGroup2Names { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the entire console app:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<ComputerInfo> computers = new List<ComputerInfo>();

            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                ps.AddScript(@"
$computers = 
@""
Server1
""@ -split [Environment]::NewLine

$oRes1 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers {

    $test = 
    @{ 
        res1 = Get-PSDrive C | Select-Object Used,Free;
        res2 = Get-PSDrive D | Select-Object Used,Free;
        res3 = hostname;
        res4 = Get-ChildItem ""c:\temp"";
        res5 = Get-ChildItem ""d:\temp""
    }

    $test
}

[PSCustomObject]$oRes1

");

                Collection<PSObject> result = ps.Invoke();
                foreach (var outputObject in result)
                {
                    computers.Add(new ComputerInfo()
                    {
                        Res1 = $"{outputObject.Properties["Res1"].Value}",
                        Res2 = $"{outputObject.Properties["Res2"].Value}",
                        Res3 = $"{outputObject.Properties["Res3"].Value}",
                        Res4 = $"{outputObject.Properties["Res4"].Value}",
                        Res5 = $"{outputObject.Properties["Res5"].Value}"
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class ComputerInfo
    {
        public string Res1 { get; set; }
        public string Res2 { get; set; }
        public string Res3 { get; set; }
        public string Res4 { get; set; }
        public string Res5 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Results:

```
ConsoleApp1.ComputerInfo,"@{Used=130977062912; Free=136249364480}","@{Used=130977062912; Free=136249364480}",Server1,"2023-06-13 2023-06-20 2023-06-21 2023-06-22 2023-06-23 2023-06-24 2023-06-26 2023-06-27 2023-06-28 2023-06-29 2023-06-30 2023-07-01 2023-07-03 2023-07-04 2023-07-05 2023-07-06 2023-07-07 2023-07-08 2023-07-10 2023-07-11 2023-07-12 2023-07-13 2023-07-14 2023-07-15 2023-07-17 2023-07-18 2023-07-19 2023-07-20 2023-07-21 2023-07-22 2023-07-24 2023-07-25 2023-07-26 2023-07-27 2023-07-28 2023-07-29 2023-07-31 2023-08-01 2023-08-02 2023-08-03 2023-08-04 2023-08-05 2023-08-07 2023-08-08 2023-08-09 2023-08-10 2023-08-11 2023-08-12 2023-08-14 2023-08-15 2023-08-16 2023-08-17 2023-08-18 2023-08-19 2023-08-21 2023-08-22 2023-08-23 2023-08-24 2023-08-25 2023-08-26 2023-08-28 2023-08-29 2023-08-30 2023-08-31 2023-09-01 2023-09-02 2023-09-04 2023-09-05 2023-09-06 2023-09-07 2023-09-08 2023-09-09 2023-09-11 2023-09-12 2023-09-13 2023-09-14 2023-09-15 2023-09-16 2023-09-18 2023-09-19 2023-09-20 2023-09-21 2023-09-22 2023-09-23 2023-09-25 2023-09-26 2023-09-27 2023-09-28 2023-09-29 2023-09-30 2023-10-02 2023-10-03 2023-10-04 2023-10-05 2023-10-06 2023-10-07 2023-10-09 2023-10-10 2023-10-11 2023-10-12 2023-10-13 2023-10-14 2023-10-16 2023-10-17 2023-10-18 2023-10-19 2023-10-20 2023-10-21 2023-10-23 2023-10-24 2023-10-25 2023-10-26 2023-10-27 2023-10-28 2023-10-30 2023-10-31 2023-11-01 2023-11-02 2023-11-03 2023-11-04 2023-11-06 2023-11-07 2023-11-08 2023-11-09 2023-11-10 2023-11-11 2023-11-13","2023-10-28 2023-10-30 2023-10-31 2023-11-01 2023-11-02 2023-11-03 2023-11-04 2023-11-06 2023-11-07 2023-11-08 2023-11-09 2023-11-10 2023-11-11 2023-11-13"
```

**Updated**

```
computers[0].Res1
{@{Used=130976595968; Free=136249831424}}
    BaseObject: "@{Used=130976595968; Free=136249831424}"
    ImmediateBaseObject: "@{Used=130976595968; Free=136249831424}"
    Members: {System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfoIntegratingCollection<System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo>}
    Methods: {System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfoIntegratingCollection<System.Management.Automation.PSMethodInfo>}
    Properties: {System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfoIntegratingCollection<System.Management.Automation.PSPropertyInfo>}
    TypeNames: Count = 2
    Dynamic View: Expanding the Dynamic View will get the dynamic members for the object
```

[image]

Comment: all your `resX` except the `hostname` one are objects not `string` so what did you expect here?

Comment: but I don't think they're objects in c#, I think it's just a string or i just don't know how to get to values as object. For example, How can I get the Used space through object notation?

Comment: you have already stringified those objects due to your class `ComputerInfo` having those properties as `string` type, there is no more dot notation possible here. change them to `PSObject` instead, or `Object`. The values are also stringified here `$"{outputObject.Properties["..."].Value}"`. Explain what you would like as a result of your code or provide a sample because you're definitely making things harder than they should be

Comment: Ok, I changed Res1 to PSObject type.   

`computers[0].Res1.Members["Used"]
null`  But if I display `computers[0].Res1` i see the correct values but can't get to them yet

Comment: i updated OP with value of `computers[0].Res1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this can help you simplify your code, it's unclear what you expect as a result from your code but what you need to do first is change the `string` type in the properties of your `ComputerInfo` class to `PSObject` or `object` instead otherwise those objects outputted from `Invoke-Command` are stored as a simple string.

You could also leverage the [`Invoke<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.invoke?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0#system-management-automation-powershell-invoke-1) overload instead and let PowerShell perform the conversion from `PSCustomObject` to `ComputerInfo`. I'm adding here a very simplified example of what this means:

```bash
Add-Type @'
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class ComputerInfo
    {
        public string ComputerName { get; set; }
        public string CUsedSpace { get; set; }
        public string CFreeSpace { get; set; }
        public string DUsedSpace { get; set; }
        public string DFreeSpace { get; set; }
        public List<string> FolderGroup1Names { get; set; }
        public List<string> FolderGroup2Names { get; set; }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static ComputerInfo[] Test()
        {
            using (PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                return ps.AddScript(@"
                    # NOTE: removed -ComputerName here for simplicity
                    Invoke-Command {
                        $psdC = Get-PSDrive C
                        $psdD = Get-PSDrive D

                        @{
                            ComputerName      = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                            CUsedSpace        = $psdC.Used
                            CFreeSpace        = $psdC.Free
                            DUsedSpace        = $psdD.Used
                            DFreeSpace        = $psdD.Free
                            FolderGroup1Names = (Get-ChildItem c:\).Name
                            FolderGroup2Names = (Get-ChildItem d:\).Name
                        }
                    }
                ")
                .Invoke<ComputerInfo>()
                .ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
'@ -WarningAction 0 -IgnoreWarnings

$result = [ConsoleApp1.Program]::Test()
$result[0].GetType()

#    Namespace: ConsoleApp1
#
# Access        Modifiers           Name
# ------        ---------           ----
# public        class               ComputerInfo : object

$result.FolderGroup1Names  # works
$result.ComputerName       # works
```

Comment: not sure what's going on here: is this still running in console app or PowerShell?

Comment: @Rod using powershell to test the code :) you can just change it to a console app

Comment: this is new to me, interesting

Comment: @Rod powershell is best for prototyping :D only downside is that you will need to change the namespace for each compilation (`Add-Type`) or restart the powershell session

Comment: How does `Get-PSDrive` get its data so fast? Does it run in parallel when multiple servers are specified?

Comment: @Rod I'm not sure if `Get-PSDrive` runs in parallel but `Invoke-Command` for sure does when remoting (32 threads by default).

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should ask this in my new thread but how do I get that into my c# object 

```Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers {
    Get-Service -Name *ssp* | Select-Object Name, Status, PSComputerName, StartType
}
                ")
                .Invoke<SspService>()
                .ToArray();
            }```

Comment: @Rod as long as you have the class `SspService` defined in your c# code that 1. is `public`, 2. has an empty or no ctor and 3. its properties are settable and match exactly the output from your `powershell.Invoke<T>()` then it should work correctly

Comment: and i don't need that hashtable part as in this thread

Comment: @Rod the hashtable in this example was used because its much easier to use a hashtable to join outputs from `Get-PSDrive`, `Get-ChildItem` and `$env:ComputerName` into a single object but is not mandatory. If you output with `Select-Object` it will work just fine as long as the 3 conditions mentioned above are met

Comment: i posted an answer so you could see code, i'll delete it

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have and I'm not getting any records back but if I paste into PowerShell I do get records.

```
....
....
....
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers {
        Get-Service -Name *ssp* | Select-Object Name, Status, PSComputerName, StartType
    }
                    ")
                    .Invoke<SspService>()
                    .ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    
        public class SspService
        {
            public string? Name { get; set; }
            public string? Status { get; set; }
            public string? PSComputerName { get; set; }
            public string? StartType { get; set; }
    
        }
```

Comment: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers { Get-Service -Name *ssp* } | Select-Object...` -> `Select-Object` goes outside of `Invoke-Command`

Comment: Thank you!!! Hey do you want me to delete this answer