# When I ask for Get-Service this way it is grouping my Names, how can I prevent that?

Tags: powershell

Given: PowerShell 5.1

When I ask for Get-Service this way it is grouping my Names, how can I prevent that?

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers {
    $var1 = Get-Service -Name *ssp* 

    @{
        ComputerName  = $env:ComputerName
        DisplayName   = $var1.DisplayName
        Name          = $var1.Name
        Status        = $var1.Status
        StartType     = $var1.StartType
    }
}
```

Unexpected Output:

```
ComputerName  Server1
StartType     {Automatic, Disabled, Automatic, Disabled}                                                                                                                                                                                        
Name          {Service1, Service2, Service3}                                                                                                                  
Status        {Running, Stopped}  

ComputerName  Server2
StartType     {Automatic, Disabled, Automatic, Disabled}                                                                                                                                                                                        
Name          {Service12, Service23, Service33}                                                                                                                  
Status        {Running, Stopped}
```

Expected Output

```
Server1  Service1
Server1  Service2
Server1  Service3
Server2  Service12
Server2  Service23
Server2  Service33
```

Comment: Do you have more than one service fitting the criteria `-Name *ssp*`? If "yes" - you should use a loop to iterate over them.

Comment: Your call to Get-Service is returning multiple objects, so you’re not accessing the properties of a *single* object - you’re actually using “Member-Access Enumeration” to return an array of the named property from multiple services - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.3 for an explanation of the behaviour you’re currently seeing…

Comment: Use `Select-Object`... `Get-Service -Name *ssp* | Select-Object DisplayName, Name...` then the `PSComputerName` property will be automatically attached to get the source

Comment: Considering that this question is associated to the past one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77483920/im-assuming-i-have-to-do-something-manual-with-res1-a-powershell-hashtable-in you should be asking your questions here and relating them to your actual code implementation instead of following up in comments in that answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're a victim of [property enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.3)!

Since PowerShell 3.0, the `.` member invocation operator has a fallback mechanism for whenever it can't resolve a given member name - it tests whether the expression to the left of `.` evaluates to a *collection*, and then attempts to construct a list of property value(s) from each of the collection items:

```
$ArrayOfObjects = @(
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Name = 'Jane'
    Number = Get-Random
  }
  [pscustomobject]@{
    Name = 'John'
    Number = Get-Random
  }
)

# The array-object stored in $ArrayOfObjects doesn't actually have a `Name` property
# - so we end up with an array consisting of the values `@($ArrayOfObjects[0].Name,...,$ArrayOfObjects[<n-1>].Name)`
$ArrayOfNameValues = $ArrayOfObjects.Name

# The array-object stored in $ArrayOfObjects doesn't have a `Number` property either
# - so we end up with an array consisting of the values `@($ArrayOfObjects[0].Number,...,$ArrayOfObjects[<n-1>].Number)`
$ArrayOfNumberValues = $ArrayOfObjects.Number
```

This is great if you want a *flat list* of individual values - but in most cases you'll probably want to retain the original data structure.

You can do that by explicitly iterating over the results from `Get-Service`:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers {
  foreach ($individualService in Get-Service -Name *ssp*) {
    @{
        ComputerName  = $env:ComputerName
        DisplayName   = $individualService.DisplayName
        Name          = $individualService.Name
        Status        = $individualService.Status
        StartType     = $individualService.StartType
    }
  }
}
```

... or you can take advantage of a pipeline-aware cmdlet like [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.3) and simplify your code significantly:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers {
  Get-Service -Name *ssp*
} |Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName'; Expression='PSComputerName'},DisplayName,Name,Status,StartupType
```